# regex:- begin with 'abc' and end immidiately when find 'xyz'

Tags: regex

regex for begin where find 'abc' end where first find 'xyz'.

I can write:- `var regex = /abc/` to match the exact `abc`.

I'm trying to read more. Any  help is appreciated.

following [tutorial](http://www.regular-expressions.info/)

Comment: I think it should be something like: abc(\w*)xyz. This will match words like: abcxyz, skjabcxyzdlks, abcslkdjlskjxyz

Comment: try here: http://gskinner.com/RegExr/

Comment: What would you like to match in a string like `"abc def abc ghi xyz jkl"`? What about `"labcoat xyz"`?

Comment: @TimPietzcker the latter. your answer seems correct. i'm not looking for word boundaries.

Comment: OK, and which of the `abc`s in the first example should start the match? The first one or the second one?

Comment: ideally the first, but in my string, 'abc' does not occur twice.

Comment: OK, in that case, `.*?` works as expected.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simplest way would be

```
/abc.*?xyz/
```

`.*?` means "Match any number of characters, as few as possible.

Answer (score 1):

You can use this regex:

```
var regex = /\babc\b.*?\bxyz\b/;
```

`\b` is for word boundaries to make it match `abc` and `xyz` specifically not `aabc` or `xyz123`